# Deployment Part in Azure Preview Portal don't respond

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I'm not able to setup continuous deployment in *Azure Preview Portal*. The deployment don't respond as shown on picture.

[image: Deployment part hang in Azure Preview Portal]

As workaround I setup the continuous deployment in *Full Azure Portal*. This created the correct build definition but I'm not able to see any builds as you can see below.

[image: Deployments error in Full Azure Portal]
Something is messed and I wouldn't like to delete the website slot and recreate them again.

Comment: What source control system have you configured this against?  VSOnline?

Comment: So have you kicked off the build in VS Online?

Comment: No over Visual Studio IDE. But the problem isn't the starting the builds but the problem is why is the deployment part hangs.

Comment: If you take a look at the build output in VS Online, you'll be able to get to the build logs and investigate what is happening with the build/deployment.  Have you looked at them?

Comment: Yes I can see in the *VS Online* Output Builds. As I said before the problem here is I can't create builds from *Azure Preview Portal*

Comment: I think you need to add some clarification to your question.  When you setup the continuous integration build from with the Azure Portal, a CI Build Definition is created in VSOnline that will build and deploy the website (I think on checkin).  You cannot create new build definitions via the web - you must do this via VS.  The idea is that when you want to deploy a new build of the website, you run the CI build and it will deploy it for you.  If you can't see an already completed build from the Azure Portal, either it wasn
't successful or there is an issue with the Portal.

Comment: You can normally create Build Definition via (old) *Full Azure Portal* and (new) *Azure Preview Portal*. When you create them in old, you can't see build results in new, and vice versa. I created them in old as workaround because as I wrote deployment part hangs as shown in picture. The question is why I can't create builds in new *Azure Preview Portal*, why deployment hangs and why tell my old portal I created *preview version of continuous deployment* when this isn't true. This is definitely a bug and i hoped someone from MS will provide answer.